# Create an embed script from a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, embed

I have a chat app built with React and bootstrapped using the CRA utility. However, I need to create an embed script that can be given to users to include in their website similar to [Intercom's](http://intercom.io). After reading [this](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-library-starter-using-webpack-es6), I understand that I have to edit my webpack config file but I don't have a clue as to how to do that. How do I go about making a React app an embed script?